# How can i use parts of the Referrer Header in an Apache Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I'm writing a generic proxy of sorts - so I can access a single host in the form of `http://<proxy-host>/<host-to-proxy-to>/<port>/<path>/` which currently uses rewrites to Proxy requests to `https://<host-to-proxy-to>:<port>/<path>`

I've got that part working and it seems to do what I want it to. However in some scenarios I'm using it with a stubborn sites that are forcing root relative urls. The application in question is not particularly easy (and in some cases impossible) to change.

My problem is how to identify the root relative URLs that are hitting apache, and proxy them to the correct host. I have identified that the correct host details are still in the path of the referrer header, so I'm trying to break apart and use the referrer path in a rewrite rule.

Updated Code Below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName wtf.devbox-cole.orion.internal
  ServerAlias wtf.devbox-cole

  RewriteEngine On

  <LocationMatch "^/$">
    Header always set X-CRAP-BASE "Its working kinda"
    Redirect 410 /
  </LocationMatch>

  <Location /web/>
    Header always set X-CRAP-BASE "Hardly Working"
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)/([0-9]*)/.*"
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%1:%2/$1 [P]
  </Location>

  <LocationMatch "^/(?<host>[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)/(?<port>[0-9]*)/(?<path>.*)">
    RewriteRule ".*" https://%{env:MATCH_HOST}:%{env:MATCH_PORT}/%{env:MATCH_PATH} [P]
    ProxyPassReverse "https://%{env:MATCH_HOST}:%{env:MATCH_PORT}/%{env:MATCH_PATH}"
  </LocationMatch>

  # Enable proxying to https://
  SSLProxyEngine On
  # Allow Proxying to https without valid cert
  SSLProxyVerify none
  # Disable Domain Nmae checking on the Certs
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  # disbaled cert expiryt Check
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

  LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/wtf_log" "%h"
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/wtf_error
</VirtualHost>
```

The above code still isn't quite working. Still trying to track down why..

Comment: Woa, great project! Would you mind sharing the URL of that proxy of yours? :-)

Comment: Apart from that: what a surprise that the documentation of the rewrite module mentions the referrer and actually gives examples. It would have been interesting to see what you learn from it. But certainly you already read through that and decided to ask here instead... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Heres my VHost definition so far: [gist](https://gist.github.com/arcticShadow/43b8a914ff12d066ef0b7ba706725343 ) - the Web locaton block is where i am trying to extract segments of of the referrer header, and pass that to the rewrite. I didnt see anything along those lines in the docs.

Comment: Please add _all_ relevant information to the question above itself. Do _not_ post additional information in comments or arbitrary off site places. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt consider my work so far to be relavant. Was posting because you asked for a link. Ill add to the question.

Comment: That is going into the right direction. But the documentation clearly states that you have to use `%1` and so on to refer to captured groups from a condition, not `$1`. So all there is left is that you have to create a regular expression that breaks apart a URL, right?

Comment: :facepalm: You are indeed correct. I hadn't noticed the difference between the `%` and `$` and was getting really confused as to why the documentation said it could be done but the way I was interpreting it said it couldn't be done. Once I have a working solution I can post an answer to my own question. Unless you wanted to post an answer and take the credit.

Comment: Just go ahead. I have very little need or credits or points ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after many attempts and reading as much documentation as I can find - I managed to solve my initial question. The following VHost block will Proxy `http://domain.com/<host>/<port>/<path>` to `https://<host>:<port>/<path>` AND it will map any requests to `/web/*` originating from that domain, back to the proper place.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com

  RewriteEngine On

  <LocationMatch "^/$">
    Header always set X-CRAP-BASE "Its working kinda"
    Redirect 410 /
  </LocationMatch>

  <Location /web/>
    Header always set X-CRAP-BASE "Hardly Working"
  </Location>

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/web/.*"
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "http://.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]*)/([0-9]*)/.*"
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%1:%2/$1 [P]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)"
  RewriteRule ".*" https://%1:%2/%3 [P]

  <LocationMatch "^/(?<host>[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]*)/(?<port>[0-9]*)/(?<path>.*)">
    ProxyPassReverse "https://%{env:MATCH_HOST}:%{env:MATCH_PORT}/%{env:MATCH_PATH}"
  </LocationMatch>

  # Enable proxying to https://
  SSLProxyEngine On
  # Allow Proxying to https without valid cert
  SSLProxyVerify none
  # Disable CN Checking on the Certs
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  # Disable Cert Expiry Check
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

  # Extra Logging
  #LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/domain.com_log" "%h"
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/domain.com_error
</VirtualHost>
```

And then i remembered how silly Referrer headers are, in that if a CSS file requests another CSS file, or an image for example, then the Referrer isnt set as expected :facepalm: